# Read files in different extensions and separators

Tags: r, csv, xls

I want to define a function in R in which you were passing a file, reading and keeping  the information in a Dada Framen in a column.
The files could be CSV, TXT or xls/xlsx; in the case of CSV and theTXT, the information could be separated by “,”, “;”, jump of lines or spaces. Some examples of the content of one of these files, would be the following one:

```
1234567890; 1234567890; 1234567890; 1234567890;


Example:
1234567890, 1234567890, 1234567890, 1234567890

Another example:
1234567890  1234567890  1234567890  1234567890;


Another example:
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

The idea would be that the function was detecting what type of file is, how the fields are separated and that it was processing the information in order to keep the fields in a dataFrame as the following one:

Tags

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

I have defined a function that does a part of the problem and that is able to detect what type of file it is ocurring and to process it if it is xls or xlsx, but I do not have clear how to do sections destined to the files of type txt or csv, which can have different types of separations.

This is my function:

```
READ_TAGS_LIST<-function(TAGS_LIST_file){
  extension<-tools::file_ext(TAGS_LIST_file)
  if(extension=="txt"){

  }
  if(extension=="csv"){

  }
  if(extension=="xls"){
    require(xlsx)
    DF_TAGS_LIST =read.xlsx(TAGS_LIST_file, 1)
    DF_TAGS_LIST<-as.data.frame(DF_TAGS_LIST)
    names(DF_TAGS_LIST)[1]<-("TAGS_IDE")
    return(DF_TAGS_LIST)
  }
  if(extension=="xlsx"){
    require(xlsx)
    DF_TAGS_LIST =read.xlsx(TAGS_LIST_file, 1)
    DF_TAGS_LIST<-as.data.frame(DF_TAGS_LIST)
    names(DF_TAGS_LIST)[1]<-("TAGS_IDE")
    return(DF_TAGS_LIST)
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fread` from `data.table` package with default `sep="auto"` option will detect the separator automatically.

```
if(extension=="txt" | extension=="csv"){
    ...
    DF_TAGS_LIST =fread(TAGS_LIST_file)
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

Assuming a file structure as this, it would also apply for space delimited files

```
a;b;c;d
1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890
```

You could use `t()` to transpose, since you need data in one column

```
if(extension=="txt" | extension=="csv"){
    ...
    DF_TAGS_LIST =as.data.frame(t(fread(TAGS_LIST_file)),row.names=FALSE)
    ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
as.data.frame(t(fread("sample_fread.dat",header="auto")),row.names=FALSE)
          V1
1 1234567890
2 1234567890
3 1234567890
4 1234567890
```

Comment: more or less it works fine, but I need the data to be saved in a single column. Now the data is stored in different columns. Is there any way to join all the columns into one?